# JBoss EAP 6.4 Infinispan Clustered cache network issue

Tags: jboss, udp, cluster-analysis, jboss6.x, infinispan

We have a 2 node clustered JBoss environment that works fine in production. Intermittently we face an issue where the 2 caches stop communicating with each other (we do not see any logs related to infinispan but we notice the application logs that conclude that the caches have stopped communicating with each other). To resolve it, we shut 1 node down temporarily. Then we bring the other node up after a couple of hours and it starts to work correctly again. Sometimes it doesn't, so we keep it shut for some more time and then it works the next time we bring it up. Very random behavior. 
It seems like an intermittent network glitch to us. So we need to involve the network team. But I do not understand what should I tell them.
My question is:
What configuration needs to be checked and how can they be checked to verify that the caches are able to or not able to communicate with each other.

My cache related settings in standalone.xml are:

````
<property name="ehcache.multicast.address" value="x.x.x.21"/>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.1" default-stack="udp">
            <stack name="udp">
                <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/>
                <protocol type="PING"/>
                <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
                <protocol type="UNICAST2"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="UFC"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                <protocol type="RSVP"/>
            </stack>
            <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                <protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
                <protocol type="MERGE2"/>
                <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
                <protocol type="UNICAST2"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="UFC"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                <protocol type="RSVP"/>
            </stack>
        </subsystem>

 <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="x.x.x.23" multicast-port="45700"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="x.x.x.24" multicast-port="45688"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
                <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="x.x.x.22" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
                <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
        <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="y.y.y.105" multicast-port="23364"/>```
````

Please let me know if any more information is required to clarify the problem. Thanks.

Update on 8th May 2020: Enabled DEBUG logs on org.infinispan and org.jgroups. Found this line in the logs: 
07:17:13,928 FINE  [STABLE] (OOB-20,shared=udp) my-host-52/ejb: received digest from my-host-51/ejb (digest=my-host-51/ejb: [4 (4)]) which does not match my own digest (my-host-52/ejb: [0 (0)]): ignoring digest and re-initializing own digest.
Does this make any sense to relate to the problem?
I can see this similar log for all caches : hibernate/ejb/singleton.

Comment: The digest warning is almost certainly because the nodes suspected each other and split into separate cluster views with a single node each, so it does sound like a network problem. Did you not see any log messages from FD?

Answer (score 0):

Without a log it is tricky to understand what is happening. Obviously lowering org.jgroups to DEBUG could generate excessive logging, but it will provide some essential info.

Comment: Have added a log statement I found at DEBUG level. Does that make any sense? Thanks.